# What is special about Bridge design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, bridge

I am reading up on bridge design pattern and find its proposition to be very trivial. From what I understand, it professes the user of interfaces with the actual concrete implementation to be used fed at run time, which is essentially dependency injection. Am I missing sometihng? What is so special about this pattern? The way I see it, it doesnt really offer anything new, just a manifestation of dependency injection. What am i missing here? Also, can you please point me to some good literature on this pattern which will help me understand it better? Whatever I have come acrossthe internet towards this has been of little help.

Come to think of it, the pattern seems to overlap with strategy pattern as well. Please help me understand the distinction between the two